# My website freezes for one minute every time I publish or update a post

Tags: posts, wp-admin

Every time I publish a new post or update an existing one, my website freezes for around one minute, although the post is updated shortly after I click the update button in the WordPress admin dashboard.
After one minute the website loads again as usual.
Obviously this is very annoying.

Is it something related to WordPress or to the database?
What can I do to solve this issue?

Here is a link to my website: [Kodi Beginner](https://kodibeginner.com)